# LogStash translate filter ignored

Tags: logstash

Im trying to add a simple translation filter to convert port number in application name:

```
filter {

    mutate
    {
      add_field => { "[source][application]" => "%{[source][port]}" }
    }
    
    translate 
    {
        field => "[source][port]"
        destination => "[source][application]"
        dictionary => {
          "80" => "HTTP"
          "443" => "SSL"
          "5432" => "Postgresql"
        }
        fallback => "__NO_MATCH"
    }

}
```

The mutate part is done correctly but translate filter is completely ignored.
In [source][application] I get the original port number and not application name or even __NO_MATCH.

What Im doing wrong? Is there a type problem?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried not using the destination? It would create a field translation, if that is the case, the targetting of a subfield in json might not work?

Comment: Removing destination parameter I got the correct value but as a direct child of _source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write the result of a `translate` filter into a field that already exists in your document, you will need to set `override => true`, if you do not set it the filter will skip the translation. [[documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html#plugins-filters-translate-override)]

But in your case it is better to not use the `mutate` filter to add the field `source.application`, there is no need for it since this field would be overwritten by the translate filter.

Just use the translate filter and it should work.

```
filter {
    translate 
    {
        field => "[source][port]"
        destination => "[source][application]"
        dictionary => {
          "80" => "HTTP"
          "443" => "SSL"
          "5432" => "Postgresql"
        }
        fallback => "__NO_MATCH"
    }
}
```